# How to adjust Tx Power for MacBook Air mid-2012 Wi-Fi card

Tags: wireless-networking, macbook

I've just learned that apparently MacBook Air mid-2012 outputs an enormous amount of power for the wireless interface, namely almost 1500mW, i.e. 1.5W!

By any measure that's an overkill and exposes users to unnecessary, quite large, amounts of radio power.

I was wondering if, what is usually referred to as "tx power" can be adjusted somehow to something signifcantly lower, say 50-100mW?

I've been googling away for the most part of the day and found nothing.

Comment: Have you downloaded and tried the Airport Utility? http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1628 it is supposed to provide the ability to adjust your transmit power settings

Comment: Well, it is installed by default but I don't see where I can change "tx power" in this app.

Comment: **(facepalm)** Airport Utility 5 has the ability to adjust transmit power.  Version 6 does not and here is a discussion about it https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3700424?start=0&tstart=0 I wish I had known this before I made the suggestion.  It *may* be possible to install the previous version though, as covered in that thread.

Comment: Hey, easier on yourself sport :) I'm going to look into that thread and try to install v.5, because 1,5W is most probably going to give me cancer or something in the long run. Thank you. I'll report back if it's possible to do what I want or not.

Comment: Alright, so it doesn't do what I need to do. Btw I found another way to install v5.6.1 described here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4172563?start=0&tstart=0 In case I wasn't clear enough, I'm not talking about AirPort base station aka wireless router/access point but the wi-fi card/chip inside a Macbook Air.

Comment: @BonGart and anyone else suggesting the AirPort Utility is wrong. That's for adjusting the AirPort Base Stations, and it only affects the base stations, not the client transmit power.

Comment: @ILIV Can you cite your source on that MacBook Air's Tx power?

Comment: Sure, I found this information via WiFiScanner v1.7.4

![Interface Info tab](http://i.imgur.com/pzG0Wg9.png)

Comment: Alright, so I've googled for this strangely high 1496mW value and turns out a lot of people see it in all sorts of situations and devices, not just MacBook. So, chances are it is a bogus value reported by WiFiScanner. Here's a reference list:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2248433?start=0&tstart=0
http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=235411&sid=c9cd5fd8fa5c2444fb980bb4218b0bcd#235411
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=969896&p=6566536#post6566536
http://www.linksysinfo.org/index.php?threads/tomato-nd-usb-mod-with-kernel-2-6-tomato-rt.31335/page-2#post-153097

Comment: I'm going to try and contact WiFiScanner developers and ask them how they pull this tx power value. Anyone knows how I can do that in Mac OS X myself?

Comment: Here we go, official answer from AccessAgility Support:

"WiFi Scanner reports info directly from API provided by Apple. The API
is reporting incorrect value of 1496 mW and has been doing this since
10.6.8 when we first released WiFi Scanner App.

The tx power of hardware used by Apple is much lower around 100mW or 50mW"

Which is such a relief! Now, back to original question. Is there a way to actually adjust tx power?